# Xubuntu 14.10 hangs on boot up

Tags: boot, disk-check

I have been using Ubuntu for the last 7 years or more but this one has me stumped. I am getting the dialog in the attached photo after misguidedly booting into Windows 8.1 and running the security updates there. I have a dual boot system with Ubuntu 14.10 and Windows 8 on a 2tB disk, Ubuntu 14.10 and Windows 8 readonly on my old 1tB disk which is also running. I have a 1 tB External drive for backups.

Previously I was successful in getting the system to boot after troubles when upgrading to Ubuntu 14.10[image]

Answer (score 1):

Well the clues were there: mounting of the external 1tB WD drive was failing. When I went into maintenance mode and commented out the lines in fstab for /dev/sdc2 and /dev/sdc3 booting was successful. However, if I plug the drive in after booting it is mounted as /dev/sdg*

Solved.